# When to cast size_t

Tags: c, casting

I'm a little confused as how to use `size_t` when other data types like `int`, `unsigned long int` and `unsigned long long int` are present in a program. I try to illustrate my confusion minimally. Imagine a program where I use

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
```

to allocate an array (one- or multidimensional). Let the call to `calloc()` be dependent on `nrow` and `sizeof(unsigned long int)`. `sizeof(unsigned long int)` is obviously fine because it returns `size_t`. But let `nrow` be such that it needs to have type `unsigned long int`. What do I do in such a case? Do I cast `nrow` in the call to `calloc()` from `unsigned long int` to `size_t`?

Another case would be

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)
```

`fgets()` expects type `int` as its second parameter. But what if I pass it an array, let's say `save`, as it's first parameter and use `sizeof(save)` to pass it the size of the array? Do I cast the call to `sizeof()` to `int`? That would be dangerous since `int` isn't guaranteed to hold all possible returns from `sizeof()`.

What should I do in these two cases? Cast, or just ignore possible warnings from tools such as `splint`?

Here is an example regarding `calloc()` (I explicitly omit error-checking for clarity!):

```
long int **arr;
unsigned long int mrow;
unsigned long int ncol;

arr = calloc(mrow, sizeof(long int *));

for(i = 0; i < mrow; i++) {
        arr[i] = calloc(ncol, sizeof(long int));
}
```

Here is an example for `fgets()` (Error-handling again omitted for clarity!):

```
char save[22];
char *ptr_save;
unsigned long int mrow
if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL) {
        save[strcspn(save, "\n")] = '\0';
        mrow = strtoul(save, &ptr_save, 10);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `sizeof(unsigned long int)` and `sizeof(long int)`? And `size_t` is `unsigned` actually.

Comment: I forgot to type `unsigned`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and `-Wconversion` (gcc). That should give you hints where you have potential problems with truncation or the sign. Juggling with signed and unsigned integers is sometimes pretty tricky.

Comment: @iharob: regardless of his correction: that would be guaranteed 0, as both have the same size: [6.2.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p6)

Comment: Unless you are dealing with something that would be out of range for the type, you can rely in most cases on the rules of integer promotion if you simply multiply `nrow` by your `unsigned long long int`.  Just ensure that `nrow * (your_var)` will not overflow an `unsigned long long int` or you're in big trouble. :)

Comment: You might want to show us the some of the warnings you're worried about.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Unsigned integer types don't overflow in C. They just wrap-around if the value doesn't fit.

Comment: @SteveSummit, they are warnings like "`fgets()` expects type `int` gets `size_t`. The `fgets()` case is obviously the one I am more worried about.

Comment: `fgets()` especially bugs me because it is so commonly used. I use `fgets()` and `strol()` or `stroul()` quite regularly to get user input. Btw, this is also another case where two functions when combined introduce different type requirements.

Comment: You don't mention warnings in your question. If that's your concern, please update your question and include examples of the warnings you're concerned about.

Comment: @KeithThompson, my concern is not necessarily about the warnings since I can e.g. guarantee that the values are > 0 at any time. But I can include a more elaborate example (ca. 10 min).

Comment: @BlueMoon True, however, it will still result in a space that is far smaller than the OP expects.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm a little confused as how to use size_t when other data types like
>   int, unsigned long int and unsigned long long int are present in a
>   program.

It is never a good idea to ignore warnings. Warnings are there to direct your attention to areas of your code that may be problematic. It is much better to take a few minutes to understand what the warning is telling you -- and fix it, then to get bit by it later when you hit a corner-case and stumble off into undefined behavior.

`size_t` itself is just a data-type like any other. While it can vary, it generally is nothing more than an `unsigned int` covering the range of positive values that can be represented by `int` including `0` (the type size was intended to be consistent across platforms, the actual bytes on each may differ). Your choice of data-type is a basic and fundamental part of programming. You choose the type based on the range of values your variable can represent (or should be limited to representing). So if whatever you are dealing with **can't be negative**, then an `unsigned` or `size_t` is the proper choice. The choice then allows the compiler to help identify areas where your code would cause that to be violated.

When you compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) which you should use on every compile, you will be warned about possible conflicts in your data-type use. (i.e. comparison between `signed` and `unsigned` values, etc...) These are **important**!

Virtually all modern **x86 & x86_64** computers use the **twos-compliment** representation for signed values. In simple terms it means that if the leftmost bit of a signed number is `1` the value is **negative**. Herein lie the subtle traps you may fall in when mixing/casting or comparing numbers of varying type. If you choose to cast an `unsigned` number to a `signed` number and that number happens to have the most significant bit populated, your large number just became a very small number.

> What should I do in these two cases? Cast, or just ignore possible
>   warnings...

You do what you do each time you are faced with warnings from the compiler. You analyze what is causing the warning, and then you fix it (or if you can't fix it -- (i.e. is comes from some library you don't have access to) -- you understand the warning well enough that you can make an educated decision to disregard it knowing you will not hit any corner-cases that would lead to undefined behavior.

In your examples (while neither should produce warning, they may on some compilers):

```
arr = calloc (mrow, sizeof(long int *));
```

What is the range of `sizeof(long int *)`? Well -- it's the range of what the pointer size can be. So, what's that? (`4 bytes` on `x86` or `8 bytes` on `x86_64`). So the range of values is `4-8`, yes that can be properly fixed with a cast to size_t if needed, or better just:

```
arr = calloc (mrow, sizeof *arr);
```

Looking at the next example:

```
char save[22];
...
fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin)
```

Here again what is the possible range of `sizeof save`? From `22 - 22`. So yes, if a warnings is produced complainting about the fact that `sizeof` returns `long unsigned` and `fgets` calls for `int`, `22` can be cast to `int`.

Comment: This "*it generally is nothing more than an `unsigned int`*" is misleading and should better read "*... an `unsigned` integer*" as for example on Linux x86_64 `size_t` is `unsigned long`.

Comment: x86_64 was just an example, it could be something else on another platform. That's why `size_t` was invented.

Comment: I knew what you were getting at, I just screwed the pooch trying to artfully explain it `:(`

Answer (score 2):

My other answer got waaaaaaay too long, so here's a short one.

1. Declare your variables of natural and appropriate types.  Let the compiler take care of most conversions.  If you have something that is or might be a size, go ahead and use `size_t`.  (Similarly, if you have something that's involved in file sizes or offsets, use `off_t`.)
2. Try not to mix signed and unsigned types.
3. If you're getting warnings about possible data loss because of larger types getting downconverted to possibly smaller types, and if you can't change the types to make the warnings go away, first (a) convince yourselves that the values, in practice, will not ever actually overflow the smaller type, then (b) add an explicit downconversion cast to make the warning go away, and for extra credit (c) add an assertion to document and enforce your assumption:

.

```
assert(size_i_need <= SIZE_MAX);
char *buf = malloc((size_t)size_i_need);
```

Answer (score 2):

> When to cast size_t

You shouldn't.

Use it where it's appropriate.

- (As you already noticed) the libc-library functions tell you where this is the case.
- Additionally use it to index arrays.

---

If in doubt the type suits your program's needs you might go for the useful assertion statement as per [*Steve Summit*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093762/694576) and if it fails start over with your program's design.

---

More on this here by *Dan Saks*: ["Why size_t matters"](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/Why-size-t-matters) and ["Further insights into size_t"](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026118/Further-insights-into-size-t)

Comment: (This is an extra question but not worth a separate post.) Regarding the `fgets()` example: Based on the articles (Great reads, thanks!) and the sloppy casting option from `size_t` to `int` it seems that `fgets()` and `size_t` don't go well together. So the best option seems to use a `define` for the `fgets()` buffer size?

Comment: @brauner: `fgets()` is older than `size_t`. We need to live with this. If the size to be passed to `fgets()` might vary, then to stay on the save side add code to test whether what you'd pass as `size` would overflow an `int`. If it is possible to use a constant things easier, indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're right, you should not ignore the warnings!  And in general, if you can, you should shy away from explicit casts, because they can make your code less reliable, or silence warning which are really trying to tell you something important.

Most of the time, I believe, the compiler should do the right thing for you.  For example, `malloc()` expects a `size_t`, and the compiler knows from the function prototype that it does, so if you write

```
int size_i_need = 10;
char *buf = malloc(size_i_need);
```

the compiler will insert the appropriate conversion from int to size_t, as necessary.  (I don't believe I've had warnings here I had to worry about, either.)

If the variables you're using are already `unsigned`, so much the better!

Similarly, if you were to write

```
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ifp);
```

the compiler will again insert an appropriate conversion.  Here, I guess I see what you're getting at, a 64-bit compiler might emit a warning about the downconversion from long to int.  Now that I think about it, I'm not sure why I haven't had that problem, because this is a common idiom.

(You also asked about passing `unsigned long` to `malloc`, and on a machine where `size_t` is smaller than `long`, I suppose that might get you warnings, too.  Is that what you were worried about?)

If you've got a downsize that you can't avoid, and your compiler or some other tool is warning about it, and you want to get rid of the warning *safely*, you could use a cast and an assertion.  That is, if you write

```
unsigned long long size_i_need = 23;
char *buf = malloc(size_i_need);
```

this might get a warning on a machine where size_t is 32 bits.  So you could silence the warning with a cast (on the assumption that your unsigned long long values will never actually be too big), and then back up your assumption with a call to `assert`:

```
unsigned long long size_i_need = 23;
assert(size_i_need <= SIZE_MAX);
char *buf = malloc((size_t)size_i_need);
```

In my experience, the biggest nuisance is printing these things out.  If you write

```
printf("int size = %d\n", sizeof(int));
```

or

```
printf("string length = %d\n", strlen("abc"));
```

on a 64-bit machine, a modern compiler will typically (and correctly) warn you that "format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'", or something to that effect.  You can fix this in two ways: cast the value to match the printf format, or change the printf format to match the value:

```
printf("int size = %d\n", (int)sizeof(int));
printf("string length = %lu\n", strlen("abc"));
```

In the first case, you're assuming that `sizeof`'s result will fit in an int (which is probably a safe bet).  In the second case, you're assuming that `size_t` is in fact `unsigned long`, which may be true on a 64-bit compiler but may not be true on some other.  So it's actually safer to use an explicit cast in the second case, too:

```
printf("string length = %lu\n", (unsigned long)strlen("abc"));
```

The bottom line is that abstract types like `size_t` don't work so well with `printf`; this is where we can see that the C++ output style of `cout << "string length = " << strlen("abc") << endl` has its advantages.

To solve this problem, there are some special `printf` modifiers that are guaranteed to match `size_t` and I think `off_t` and a few other abstract types, although they're not so well known.  (I wasn't sure where to look them up, but while I've been composing this answer, some commenters have already reminded me.)  So the best way to print one of these things (if you can remember, and unless you're using old compilers) would be

```
printf("string length = %zu\n", strlen("abc"));
```

Bottom line:

1. You obviously don't have to worry about passing plain `int` or plain `unsigned` to a function like `calloc` that expects `size_t`.
2. When calling something that might result in a downcast, such as passing a `size_t` to `fgets` where `size_t` is 64 bits but `int` is 32, or passing `unsigned long long` to `calloc` where `size_t` is only 32 bits, you might get warnings.  If you can't make the passed-in types smaller (which in the general case you're not going to be able to do), you'll have little choice to silence the warnings but to insert a cast.  In this case, to be strictly correct, you might want to add some assertions.

With all of that said, I'm not sure I've actually answered your question, so if you'd like further clarification, please ask.

Comment: It would be better to `size_t size_i_need ...`. Why would you use `int` there? Note there is a modifier for `printf` since C99: `"%zu"`: no problem at all. For `stdint.h` types, there is `inttypes.h` which provides proper conversion strings.

Comment: You don't have to cast to avoid warnings. There's `%zu` to print `size_t` (C99). Worse, casting to `int` may result in loss of information. (I didn't downvote, btw).

Comment: I would not list the C++-stuff here. I know lots of ppl who think this is a missuse of the shift operator. (No further discussion, however!

Comment: Something to [**bookmark**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). Note that assigning `size_t` to `int` is **never** a safe bet, as one is _unsigned_!

Comment: @Olaf: Why would I use `int` there?  In a program, because int is often a very natural type if I've got a variable counting some number of things.  In this example, because the question I was answering was about mixing `size_t` with other types, and I thought this was a good (and realistic) way to illustrate it.

Comment: @Olaf: if converting `size_t` to `int` is _never_ a safe bet (about which I would disagree), how is one ever to call `fgets`?

Comment: Olaf and @BlueMoon, thanks for saving me the trouble of looking up `%zu`!  (I knew it was there somewhere...)

Comment: @SteveSummit: It is without additional constraints. As both often have the same size or even rank, you cannot **in general** assign a sized to an unsigned. The other direction requires the signed to be able to hold all values of the unsigned. which actually requires it to have a larger size than the unsigned as one bit for the sign is required. And as `size_t` is most times at least the same size as `int` ....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't downvote you and this is certainly not a type of answer that deserves to be downvoted. +1 for back to 0.

Comment: @ brauner: Thanks, although at this point I'm starting to think it deserves a downvote for being too long and rambling...

Comment: I dislike that `assert()` strategy somewhat. `assert()` should only be used in debugging as far as I know.

Comment: How best to use assertions is certainly a debatable topic.  Me, I think they're perfect for explicitly documenting and enforcing my otherwise-implicit assumptions.  Here, "even though the compiler is warning, I know the actual values will always fit in the smaller type" is just such an assumption.  But then, it's true, there's the question of whether to leave the assertions enabled in production code, which isn't always possible.